# Mule : Use dynamic config-ref based on input values

Tags: dynamic, configuration, mule, mulesoft

I'm trying to connect to SQL Database with some configuration. But based on the input from the API we are supposed to hit different DB.

As of now, we have the code as

```
<choice doc:name="Check myFlag">
  <when expression="#[flowVars.myFlag == 'true']">
    <db:stored-procedure config-ref="Database_Configuration_1" doc:name="DB_config_1">
      <db:dynamic-query><![CDATA[#[flowVars.callSPName]]]></db:dynamic-query>
    </db:stored-procedure>    
  </when>
  <otherwise>   
    <db:stored-procedure config-ref="Database_Configuration_2" doc:name="DB_config_2">
      <db:dynamic-query><![CDATA[#[flowVars.callSPName]]]></db:dynamic-query>
    </db:stored-procedure>      
  </otherwise>
</choice>
```

Instead of repeating `<db:stored-procedure../>` twice, is there a way where I can set a flow var with the DB config reference and use it?

Something like,

```
<db:stored-procedure config-ref="#[flowvars.db_config]" doc:name="DB_config_2">
  <db:dynamic-query><![CDATA[#[flowVars.callSPName]]]></db:dynamic-query>
</db:stored-procedure>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Mule 3, no. config-ref's are evaluated at application startup, not runtime.

In Mule 4 this is possible using Dynamic Configurations: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-sdk/1.1/static-dynamic-configs

Potential Mule 3 solutions documented here: https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-configure-connector-with-dynamic-parameters

Comment: But we have our whole project running in Mule 3. Not sure how much effort it would take to move to Mule 4.

Answer (score 0):

Put the DB call inside a sub-flow and call it from the rest of the flows with a `<flow-ref>`.

Comment: This is the exact approach we have it currently. But now we are trying to change from dynamic query to parameterised query which gives better performance improvement. In parameterised DB call, we can't pre-populate query in parent flow and pass it to sub-flow as in dynamic query.